# Access ServiceNow API which is okta Enabled

Tags: okta, servicenow, okta-api, servicenow-rest-api

I would like to get list of all Incidents which are in "Awaiting caller feedback State" in ServiceNow. Our servicenow is Okta enabled.

Can you please let us know how can I access Servicenow API which is Okta enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The ServiceNow REST Api uses basic authentication by default. This is separate from the authentication method used to login users. You should be able to use the [default example](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/madrid-application-development/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/c_TableAPI.html#c_TableAPI) to make a call without worrying about Okta. Here's their Python example:

```
#Need to install requests package for python
import requests

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/problem?sysparm_limit=1'

# Eg. User name="username", Password="password" for this code sample.
user = 'username'
pwd = 'password'

# Set proper headers
headers = {"Accept":"application/xml"}

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200: 
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Error Response:', response.content)
    exit()

# Decode the XML response into a dictionary and use the data
print(response.content)
```